# How to I post this video?

Tags: wordpress, video, posting

I have tried to post this video to our word press site using the same approach via youtube approach and code.  How do get this to work?  Thanks.

```
{
"talk": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Al Gore: Averting the climate crisis",
    "description": "With the same humor and humanity he exuded in <em>An Inconvenient Truth,<\/em> Al Gore spells out 15 ways that individuals can address climate change immediately, from buying a hybrid to inventing a new, hotter \"brand name\" for global warming.",
    "slug": "al_gore_on_averting_climate_crisis",
    "recorded_at": "2006-02-25 00:00:00",
    "published_at": "2006-06-27 00:11:00",
    "updated_at": "2014-07-03 20:42:24",
    "viewed_count": 2459958,
    "emailed_count": 720,
    "commented_count": 239,
    "event": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "TED2006"
    },
    "images": [{
        "image": {
            "size": "113x85",
            "url": "http:\/\/images.ted.com\/images\/ted\/205_113x85.jpg"
        }
    }, {
        "image": {
            "size": "240x180",
            "url": "http:\/\/images.ted.com\/images\/ted\/205_240x180.jpg"
        }
    }, {
        "image": {
            "size": "480x360",
            "url": "http:\/\/images.ted.com\/images\/ted\/205_480x360.jpg"
        }
    }],
    "image_16x9": false,
    "media": {
        "internal": {
            "64k": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-64k.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
                  "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-180k.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
          "180k": {
            },
            "320k": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-320k.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "450k": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-450k.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "600k": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-600k.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "950k": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-950k.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "podcast-light": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-light.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "podcast-regular": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "podcast-high": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-480p.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "audio-podcast": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006.mp3?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "podcast-low-en": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-low-en.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            },
            "podcast-high-en": {
                "uri": "http:\/\/download.ted.com\/talks\/AlGore_2006-480p-en.mp4?apikey=16c11a6054506983485e20e837125c1da6c5a46a"
            }
        }
    },
    "languages": {
        "sq": {
            "name": "Albanian"
        },
        "ar": {
            "name": "Arabic"
        },
        "bg": {
            "name": "Bulgarian"
        },
        "zh-cn": {
            "name": "Chinese, Simplified"
        },
        "zh-tw": {
            "name": "Chinese, Traditional"
        },
        "hr": {
            "name": "Croatian"
        },
        "nl": {
            "name": "Dutch"
        },
        "en": {
            "name": "English",
            "native": true
        },
        "fr": {
            "name": "French"
        },
        "fr-ca": {
            "name": "French, Canadian"
        },
        "gl": {
            "name": "Galician"
        },
        "de": {
            "name": "German"
        },
        "el": {
            "name": "Greek"
        },
        "gu": {
            "name": "Gujarati"
        },
        "he": {
            "name": "Hebrew"
        },
        "hi": {
            "name": "Hindi"
        },
        "hu": {
            "name": "Hungarian"
        },
        "id": {
            "name": "Indonesian"
        },
        "it": {
            "name": "Italian"
        },
        "ja": {
            "name": "Japanese"
        },
        "ko": {
            "name": "Korean"
        },
        "lv": {
            "name": "Latvian"
        },
        "lt": {
            "name": "Lithuanian"
        },
        "rup": {
            "name": "Macedo"
        },
        "mk": {
            "name": "Macedonian"
        },
        "fa": {
            "name": "Persian"
        },
        "pl": {
            "name": "Polish"
        },
        "pt": {
            "name": "Portuguese"
        },
        "pt-br": {
            "name": "Portuguese, Brazilian"
        },
        "ro": {
            "name": "Romanian"
        },
        "ru": {
            "name": "Russian"
        },
        "sr": {
            "name": "Serbian"
        },
        "sk": {
            "name": "Slovak"
        },
        "sl": {
            "name": "Slovenian"
        },
        "es": {
            "name": "Spanish"
        },
        "sw": {
            "name": "Swahili"
        },
        "sv": {
            "name": "Swedish"
        },
        "tl": {
            "name": "Tagalog"
        },
        "th": {
            "name": "Thai"
        },
        "tr": {
            "name": "Turkish"
        },
        "uk": {
            "name": "Ukrainian"
        },
        "ur": {
            "name": "Urdu"
        }
    },
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "alternative energy"
    }, {
        "tag": "cars"
    }, {
        "tag": "climate change"
    }, {
        "tag": "culture"
    }, {
        "tag": "environment"
    }, {
        "tag": "global issues"
    }, {
        "tag": "politics"
    }, {
        "tag": "science"
    }, {
        "tag": "sustainability"
    }, {
        "tag": "technology"
    }],
    "themes": [{
        "theme": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Presentation Innovation"
        }
    }, {
        "theme": {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "A Greener Future?"
        }
    }, {
        "theme": {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "Bold Predictions, Stern Warnings"
        }
    }, {
        "theme": {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "Design That Matters"
        }
    }, {
        "theme": {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "Not Business as Usual"
        }
    }, {
        "theme": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Technology, History and Destiny"
        }
    }],
    "speakers": [{
        "speaker": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Al Gore"
        }
    }],
    "ratings": [{
        "rating": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Funny",
            "count": 439
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Courageous",
            "count": 122
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Confusing",
            "count": 45
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Beautiful",
            "count": 46
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 21,
            "name": "Unconvincing",
            "count": 209
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Longwinded",
            "count": 90
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Informative",
            "count": 361
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Inspiring",
            "count": 337
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Fascinating",
            "count": 91
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Ingenious",
            "count": 49
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "Persuasive",
            "count": 227
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "Jaw-dropping",
            "count": 84
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Obnoxious",
            "count": 96
        }
    }, {
        "rating": {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "OK",
            "count": 139
        }
    }]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted is in JSON format.  For WordPress, your best bet is to either use an embed link in the HTML tab of the WYSIWYG -- or just use the built in media library tool for embedding any type of media. This explains it reasonably well enough. http://youtu.be/aejMIghQKYo?t=2m4s